# Set rounded corner when top or bottom cell is hidden in Inset Grouped table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with static cells. I am hiding some of the cells based on some conditions by setting the height of the cell as 0 in the **heightForRowAtIndexPath** method like below.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self shouldHideCell:indexPath]) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am setting the style of the **UITableView** as **Inset Grouped**. So when I hide the first or last cell in a section the cells don't get the expected rounded corners properly. Is there any way to have the rounded corners when setting height as 0 for the first or last cell?

[image]

Comment: It be easier to just no show the cells at all (by giving the correct number of rows in section) instead of making their height equals to zero.

Comment: But we have the cells implemented as static cells.

Comment: @NithinDevN Did you find the solution on this one?

Comment: @geohei I am dynamically finding the first or last cell and setting the corner radius programatically.